# Google Forms, как проверить наличие отправляемого e-mail в Таблице?

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script, google-forms

Как сделать проверку наличия e-mail в Таблице?

Например, пользователь вводить e-mail в поле, а система ему сообщает, что данный e-mail занят.

Comment: Опыт пройдёт. Вы наверное уже  попробовали, дополните  вопрос кодом.

Comment: В том и проблема, у меня куча вариантов в голове, но я незнаю...

Comment: Толи это должна быть регулярка, то ли триггер (если триггер то когда он должен срабатывать)

Comment: Не носите в голове, откройте едитор и туда их залейте. Совсем необязательно, что они будут сразу рабочими и выполнят, то что от них ожидалось.

Comment: Можно лы как-то перекрыть response?

Comment: @Space_UA, соблюдайте правила. Сформулируйте задачу. Определитесь у вас Формы или Листы http://gdriveru.blogspot.ru/2014/11/drivenames.html.

Comment: Ну как бы форма имеет внутри себя лист...

Comment: @Space_UA, вам нужна помощь или что-то другое? От чего вы так ленитесь? Форма не "как бы" и точно не имеет Лист. Поизведите ревизию своих знаний. Выше вы пишите, что у вас есть какие-то прдетсавления, но после несете какую-то глупость.

Comment: Под пониманием листа я имел ввиду таблицу в которую форма записывает данные.

Comment: @Space_UA, зачем вам делать проверку в Таблице, если существует влидация Формы?

Comment: @oshliaer увы но у меня не получилось. Все что нужно - это просто проверить зарегистрирован ли уже данный мейл.

Comment: @Space_UA, где зарегистрирован!? Т.е. присутствует в Таблице?

Comment: @oshliaer да, даная форма представляет из себя регистрацию на олимпиаду в университете.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этого сделать нельзя, используя Формы. Из содержимого [google-forms](/questions/tagged/google-forms):

> Формы также не имеют програмного интерфейса для манипулирования в режиме опроса.

В вопросе представлена классическая ошибка неосведомленности возможностей сервиса. Скорей всего, его переоценка. Google Apps Script - полностью серверная технология. Общаться с пользователем она умеет только через специаьльный программный интерфейс [Class google.script.run (Client-side API)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Понятное дело, Формы этот интерфейс в режиме опроса не поддерживают.

Выходом может быть реализация собственной формы на базе [HtmlService и web-app](http://gdriveru.blogspot.ru/2015/02/FILEUPLOAD.html).

Другим выходом может быть запрет для пользователя отпрвлять Форму более одного раза, но тогда он должен иметь аккаунт Google.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Space_UA, с подсказки добавил еще один вариант.